# How to identify shapes in an image

Tags: image-processing

I have an image like that:
[image]

And I want to identify shapes in it:

[image]

I consider ComponentMeasurements and HighlightImage but I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: you might be interested in `ImageCorrelate`.

Comment: Look at MorphologicalComponents. For something simple  like this it should work fine.

Comment: I use ImageCorrelate and solve the problem.Thanks!

Comment: You can post your own solution as an answer, it is encouraged here.

Comment: @b3m2a1 MorphologicalComponents won't help here since the shapes are too close together. They are, exactly as the shapes themselves connected by an 8-neighborhood and cannot be separated easily.